# How to create a class that shows multiple UIImageViews in a line from an Array?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, frontend

I am running into a weird bug while trying to create a visual element within collection view cells. The class takes an array of UserModels and aligns all the profile pictures in a line. If there are more than 4 users in an array the last image view is a blurred image with a '+N' to let users know there are more users that can't fit on screen.

Actual Behavior:

[image]

Expected Behavior:

[image]

The image corrects itself once you go to another screen and come back.

This is the class I've created to get the following result.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class UserStack: UIView{
    
    var userArray: [UserModel]!
    var size: CGFloat = 50
    
    init(userArray: [UserModel]){
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        self.userArray = userArray
        
        if self.userArray.count <= 4{
            fourOrLess()
        }else{
            fiveOrMore()
        }
    }
    
    func fourOrLess(){
        var spacing: CGFloat = 0
        userArray.forEach { user in
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            guard let url = user.imageURL else {return}
            
            
            imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: url)) { i, e, c, u in
                if let e = e{
                    print("DEBUG: Error setting userStack - \(e)")
                    return
                }
                
                self.addSubview(imageView)
                self.bringSubviewToFront(imageView)
                
                imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                imageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.size * 0.4
                imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
                imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.75
                imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
                
                ///LAYOUT
                imageView.setDimensions(height: self.size, width: self.size)
                imageView.centerY(inView: self)
                imageView.anchor(left: self.leftAnchor, paddingLeft: spacing)
                
                //DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
                    spacing += (self.size - 10)
               // }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fiveOrMore(){
        var count: Int = 1
        var spacing: CGFloat = 0
        
        userArray.forEach { user in
        if count < 4{
            count += 1
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            guard let url = user.imageURL else {return}
            
            
            imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: url)) { i, e, c, u in
                if let e = e{
                    print("DEBUG: Error setting userStack - \(e)")
                    return
                }
                
                self.addSubview(imageView)
                self.bringSubviewToFront(imageView)
                
                imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                imageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.size * 0.4
                imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
                imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.75
                imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
                
                ///LAYOUT
                imageView.setDimensions(height: self.size, width: self.size)
                imageView.centerY(inView: self)
                imageView.anchor(left: self.leftAnchor, paddingLeft: spacing)
                
               
                    spacing += (self.size - 10)
                    
                }
            
        
        }else{
            ///NUMBER VIEW
            let numberImageView = UIImageView()
            let blurView = UIView()
            let numberLabel = UILabel()
            guard let _URL = userArray.last?.imageURL else {return}
            numberImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: _URL)) { i, e, c, u in
                if let e = e{
                    print("DEBUG: Error setting userStack - \(e)")
                    return
                }
                
                self.addSubview(numberImageView)
                
                numberImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                numberImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                numberImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.size * 0.4
                numberImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
                //numberImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.75
                //numberImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
                
                numberImageView.addSubview(blurView)
                
                blurView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                blurView.backgroundColor = .init(white: 0.2, alpha: 0.9)
                blurView.layer.cornerRadius = self.size * 0.4
                blurView.layer.masksToBounds = true
                blurView.layer.borderWidth = 0.75
                blurView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
                
                blurView.addSubview(numberLabel)
                
                numberLabel.text = "+\(self.userArray.count - 3)"
                numberLabel.font = .poppinsMedium(size: 14)
                numberLabel.textColor = .white
                
                ///LAYOUT
                numberImageView.setDimensions(height: self.size, width: self.size)
                numberImageView.centerY(inView: self)
                numberImageView.anchor(left: self.leftAnchor, paddingLeft: spacing)
                numberImageView.bringSubviewToFront(blurView)
                
                blurView.setDimensions(height: self.size, width: self.size)
                blurView.center(inView: numberImageView)
                numberLabel.center(inView: blurView)
                
                
                
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
}
```

UIHelper Functions:

```
extension UIView {
    func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil,
                left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil,
                bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil,
                right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil,
                paddingTop: CGFloat = 0,
                paddingLeft: CGFloat = 0,
                paddingBottom: CGFloat = 0,
                paddingRight: CGFloat = 0,
                width: CGFloat? = nil,
                height: CGFloat? = nil) {
        
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        if let top = top {
            topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: paddingTop).isActive = true
        }
        
        if let left = left {
            leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left, constant: paddingLeft).isActive = true
        }
        
        if let bottom = bottom {
            bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -paddingBottom).isActive = true
        }
        
        if let right = right {
            rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right, constant: -paddingRight).isActive = true
        }
        
        if let width = width {
            widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
        }
        
        if let height = height {
            heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
        }
    }
    
    func center(inView view: UIView, yConstant: CGFloat? = 0) {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: yConstant!).isActive = true
    }
    
    func centerX(inView view: UIView, topAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, paddingTop: CGFloat? = 0) {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        
        if let topAnchor = topAnchor {
            self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: paddingTop!).isActive = true
        }
    }
    
    func centerY(inView view: UIView, leftAnchor: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil,
                 paddingLeft: CGFloat = 0, constant: CGFloat = 0) {
        
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: constant).isActive = true
        
        if let left = leftAnchor {
            anchor(left: left, paddingLeft: paddingLeft)
        }
    }
  
    
    func setDimensions(height: CGFloat, width: CGFloat) {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
        widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
    }
}
```

How do I make this class more dependable so I can get the expected result every time?

I'm thinking perhaps make an array of UIImageView and return it to my collection view cell.

Comment: What is the UIImage method `sd_setImage()`? Where does it domes from, and what does it do? Show us that code, or a link to the docs for the framework it comes from.

Comment: This line doesn't make sense, and should generate a compiler error: `imageView.setDimensions(height: self.size, width: self.size)` (But then you don't show the code for setDimensions. You need to provide the code for all the relevant functions you're calling in the code you posted.

Comment: the sd_setImage() is from the SDWebImage cocoapod

Comment: I have added the .setDimensions extension to the post

Comment: And what does the sd_setImage function do? Why does it take a closure? What do all those parameters to the closure mean? (Don't force the people you are asking for help to ask you a bunch of questions, then have to go hunt down the framework(s) you are using, read about them, and do a bunch of work. Edit your question to include all the information a reader needs to understand your problem.)

Comment: My apologies and I hear you. The function takes the UIImageView and changes its image by downloading the image from the URL you pass in. The closure gives you access to the returned image(i), cache(c), error(e), and URL(u). You can use the .sd_setImage without the closure as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't call async methods in a loop without some form of synchronization otherwise you will have strange side effects. I am willing to bet this is the reason you have inconsistent results.

Download all your images first and then display them in your view.

You can use combine to fetch all the images really easily.

```
struct ImageLoader {
    let urls: [URL]

    func publish() -> AnyPublisher<[UIImage], Error> {
        urls.publisher
            .flatMap {
                URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: $0)
            }
            .mapError { $0 as Error }
            .compactMap { $0.data }
            .compactMap { UIImage(data: $0) }
            .collect()
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

You can use the ImageLoader like so:

```
var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
func fetchImages(_ urls: [URL], completion: @escaping ([UIImage]) -> Void) {
    ImageLoader(urls: urls)
        .publish()
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .sink { result in
            print("Result: \(result)")
        } receiveValue: { images in
            completion(images)
        }
        .store(in: &subscriptions)
}
```

As for your UserStack you can do something like this:

```
class UserStack2: UIView {

    var size: CGFloat = 50

    init(images: [UIImage]) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        addImages(images)
    }

    func createImageView(with image: UIImage, spacing: CGFloat) {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

        self.addSubview(imageView)
        self.bringSubviewToFront(imageView)

        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.size * 0.4
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.75
        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        imageView.setDimensions(height: self.size, width: self.size)
        imageView.centerY(inView: self)
        imageView.anchor(left: self.leftAnchor, paddingLeft: spacing)
    }

    func createPlaceHolderView(withValue value: Int, spacing: CGFloat) {
        let numberImageView = UIImageView()
        let blurView = UIView()
        let numberLabel = UILabel()

        self.addSubview(numberImageView)

        numberImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        numberImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        numberImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.size * 0.4
        numberImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        //numberImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.75
        //numberImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        numberImageView.addSubview(blurView)
        blurView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        blurView.backgroundColor = .init(white: 0.2, alpha: 0.9)
        blurView.layer.cornerRadius = self.size * 0.4
        blurView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        blurView.layer.borderWidth = 0.75
        blurView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        blurView.addSubview(numberLabel)

        numberLabel.text = "+\(value)"
        //                numberLabel.font = .poppinsMedium(size: 14)
        numberLabel.textColor = .white

        numberImageView.setDimensions(height: self.size, width: self.size)
        numberImageView.centerY(inView: self)
        numberImageView.anchor(left: self.leftAnchor, paddingLeft: spacing)
        numberImageView.bringSubviewToFront(blurView)

        blurView.setDimensions(height: self.size, width: self.size)
        blurView.center(inView: numberImageView)
        numberLabel.center(inView: blurView)
    }

    func addImages(_ images: [UIImage]) {

        let maxImages = 4
        var spacing: CGFloat = 0

        images.prefix(maxImages).forEach { image in
            createImageView(with: image, spacing: spacing)
            spacing += (self.size - 10)
        }

        if images.count > maxImages {
            createPlaceHolderView(withValue: images.count - maxImages, spacing: spacing)
        }
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok updated. I also added some clarification as to why you shouldn't make async calls in a loop. You may wanna check that out. My linkedin username is robertleecrabtree